# counterexamples with complex function

Tags: functions, examples-counterexamples

I want to find counterexamples for the following "states":

if $f:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ be a complex function such that
$$|f(x-y)|=|f(x)-f(y)|,\qquad \forall x ,y\in\mathbb{C}.$$

prove or disprove 
 $$f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y),\forall x,y\in\mathbb{C}?$$
Can you give me a hint of what examples may work?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean $f(x+y)\neq f(x)+f(y)$ for *all* $x,y\in\mathbb{C}$ or for *some* $x,y\in\mathbb{C}$? And what do you mean by "counterexample"? It seems that you want to find an example of a function having both properties.

Comment: for some $x,y\in C$

Comment: @Vincent Distance preserving means $\lvert f(x) - f(y) \rvert = \lvert x - y \rvert$.

Comment: I'll delete my comment...

Comment: The first condition has a few trivial implications. (1) $f(0) = 0$ - take $x = y$. (2) $\lvert f(-y)  \rvert = \lvert f(y) \rvert$ for all $y$ - take $x = 0$.

Comment: You can easily arrived at $|f(nx)| \leq n |f(x)|$. I was hoping this thing to be much easier to solve to be honest ...

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/312737/a-variant-of-cauchy-type-functional-equation-conjecture

Comment: The question is pretty much answered in that last link, you should post that as an answer @math110